# Change Status Bar Color in Real Time

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, statusbar

I am moving in a side menu view controller ([ENSwiftSideMenu](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu)) with an animation. Since the side menu's background color is a pretty dark blue, I'd like to have the status bar, that is black by default, turn light while the menu is visible.
With `View controller-based status bar appearance` being set to `YES` (also tried `NO`) inside the `info.plist`, I tried to implement the following code which did, unfortunately, not work:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Also, I tried this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .default
}
```

Any idea how to make it work?
Thanks!

Comment: If i understood correctly.you want your ENSwiftSideMenu status bar to be dark blue and the mainVC status bar to normal or diff colour...

Comment: No I want the status bar to be white when the side menu is shown.

Comment: code updated again.hope, I understood correctly this time....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Code:

In your AppDelegate:

```
     var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
     navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()] // If you want to change title colour
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default
```

//Update your plist with below code

```
     View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

In your ViewController:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     // UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
}

func sideMenuWillOpen() {
    print("sideMenuWillOpen")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
}

func sideMenuWillClose() {
    print("sideMenuWillClose")
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default 
}
```

[image]

Output from the above code.You can use some sort of UIAnimation to sync the effect..

Let me know.If the code works for you...

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I don't want to have a background for the status bar but the status bar's content to actually turn light.

Answer (score 0):

Updating status bar style directly is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622923-setstatusbarstyle), and will not work when view controller-based status bar appearance is enabled.

Instead, each controller has to provide its preferred status bar style, and the framework responsible for displaying each controller should implement `childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle` and provide the correct child controller for status bar appearance. Unfortunately, `ENSwiftSideMenu` does not support that, and thus you will have a hard time implementing this with view controller-based status bar appearance. You should open an issue with the original developer, but I suggest also switching to a better written framework.