# Swift 3 / How to overlap Root's UINavigationBar with UIViewController's UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to recreate the navigation behavior from Tinder. For that I have translated a [Framework delivering the NavigationBar](https://github.com/davidseek/SLPagingViewSwift-Swift-3-Tinder-Twitter) into Swift 3.

The test App is pretty simple. I've created a test [git project](https://github.com/davidseek/test), if someone is interested.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var controller: SLPagingViewSwift!
var nav: UINavigationController?
var home: ViewController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let orange = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 69.0/255, blue: 0.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    let gray = UIColor(red: 0.84, green: 0.84, blue: 0.84, alpha: 1.0)

    let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    self.home = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
    let vc2 = ViewController()
    vc2.view.backgroundColor = .red
    let vc3 = ViewController()
    vc3.view.backgroundColor = .blue


    var homeBtn = UIImage(named: "profile")
    homeBtn = homeBtn?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    var vc2Btn = UIImage(named: "gear")
    vc2Btn = vc2Btn?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    var vc3Btn = UIImage(named: "chat")
    vc3Btn = vc3Btn?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

    let items = [UIImageView(image: homeBtn),
                 UIImageView(image: vc2Btn),
                 UIImageView(image: vc3Btn)]

    let controllers = [self.home!,
                       vc2,
                       vc3] as [UIViewController]

    self.controller = SLPagingViewSwift(items: items, controllers: controllers, showPageControl: false)

    self.controller.pagingViewMoving = ({ subviews in
        if let imageViews = subviews as? [UIImageView] {
            for imgView in imageViews {
                var c = gray
                let originX = Double(imgView.frame.origin.x)

                if (originX > 45 && originX < 145) {
                    c = self.gradient(originX, topX: 46, bottomX: 144, initC: orange, goal: gray)
                }
                else if (originX > 145 && originX < 245) {
                    c = self.gradient(originX, topX: 146, bottomX: 244, initC: gray, goal: orange)
                }
                else if(originX == 145){
                    c = orange
                }
                imgView.tintColor = c
            }
        }
    })

    self.nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.controller)
    self.window?.rootViewController = self.nav
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true

}
```

In my `UIViewController`, I want a new `UIViewController` to be pushed within the `UINavigationController` stack *(to have the back button and the back swipe)*, once a Cell is clicked.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SegueVC")
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    appDelegate.controller?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    //appDelegate.nav?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

The problem is, that the SegueVC has the same `UINavigationBar` as the Root.

[image]

Basically I want the `UINavigationBar` of the `SegueVC` to overlap the bar of the Root Controller to have this:

[image]

It doesn't makes any difference if I push the SegueVC on the `controller` or the `nav`.

```
appDelegate.controller?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
//appDelegate.nav?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

The structure as shown in the AppDelegate: `nav` is the `rootViewController` of `window` and the `UINavigationController` of the `var controller: SLPagingViewSwift!`.

```
self.nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.controller)
self.window?.rootViewController = self.nav
self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I was thinking about presenting the SegueVC animated outside the navigation stack, but then I'm missing the build-in back button and the swipe back gesture. What are my options? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: You can do this by setting up a container to your mainVC and move it accordingly...i believe twitter animation is easy thing  to achieve..i am using same sort of animation transition in my project. it looks cool...cheers

Comment: so. i have a container on my mainVC and animate it's visibility?

Comment: thats how all sideMenuView works. i strongly recommend to check this project in  giithub https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu and also check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059328/change-status-bar-color-in-real-time/40061614#40061614

Comment: thank you very much for this input! feel free to answer it, i'll upvote for sure

Comment: if you want to achieve your first screencast from ur post. i believe you can easily  hide your statusBar and navigationBar. and place an UIView top of the navigation bar position check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176803/swift-navigation-bar-background-color-white-does-not-work/40178657#40178657  and place an uiview lager then storyBoard like view.frame.width + 100 (whatever the size works for you) and play with the UIView(you can use container to) offset position when swipeGesture detected ...I hope you get this done soon...cheers

Comment: Check this link related to twitter animation https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/InteractiveSlideOutMenu    https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/LeftSlideoutMenu fairly simple project...

Comment: @Joe could you please summarize your comments. i'm currently playing with the tutorial and git from the last comment and that will be what i have needed. i'm far from done, but that is what i have wanted. thank you VERY much

Comment: no worries mate. I am just returning your favour.if you remember....cheers

Comment: i do. thank you. once you're done with the answer, i will accept it.

Comment: @Joe , do you want to post an answer out of your comments? It helped and answered my question

Comment: glad I helped you.ok.thanks

Comment: i will post the answer.cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting up a container to your mainVC and move it accordingly...i believe twitter animation is easy thing to achieve.I am using same sort of animation transition in my project.

I,strongly recommend to check this project in giithub
https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu and also check my answer from this link [Change Status Bar Color in Real Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059328/change-status-bar-color-in-real-time/40061614#40061614)

if you want to achieve your first screencast from ur post. I believe you can easily hide your statusBar and navigationBar. and place an UIView top of the navigation bar position check my answer  [Swift Navigation bar background color white does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176803/swift-navigation-bar-background-color-white-does-not-work/40178657#40178657)  and place an uiview lager then storyBoard like view.frame.width + 100 (whatever the size works for you) and play with the UIView(you can use container to) offset position when swipeGesture detected.

Check this link related to twitter animation https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/InteractiveSlideOutMenu https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/LeftSlideoutMenu

**Note:** Above,answer based on the early conversation between me & the question owner.