# How to check if current UIViewController is part of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

In my App the `UIViewController` "`ProfilVC`" is part of the `UINavigationController` "`nav`".

But in another Scene, i'm **presenting** "`ProfilVC`" to reuse the same `UIViewController` but with different data.

```
let vc = tweetsStb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfilVC") as! ProfilVC
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Within `didSelectRowAt`, I'm presenting another `UIViewController`. And here I need to check if `self` (`ProfilVC`) is currently part of the `nav` or presented on top.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = tweetsStb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TweetCommentsVC") as! TweetCommentsVC
    let post = tweets[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section]
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TweetPostCell
    vc.commentCounterString = cell.commentLabel.text!
    vc.post = post
    vc.avatare = avatare
    nav?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This code works perfect if `ProfilVC` is part of `nav`.

But I need `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` if `ProfilVC` is presented on top.

What I need is something like this:

```
if(nav?.topViewController?.isKind(of: ProfilVC.self) != nil) {
    nav?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem with this code is, that `ProfilVC` is always part of `nav`. I need to check if `ProfilVC` as `"self"`/"the current visible one" is part of `nav` or presented on top...

What is the best approach to accomplish my wanting? Help is very appreciated.

PS: Present the second instance of `ProfilVC` within `nav` is no option because I need `ProfilVC` in this [case to overlapp the UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187545/swift-3-how-to-overlap-roots-uinavigationbar-with-uiviewcontrollers-uinaviga) of `nav`.

Comment: down vote at least care to comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every ViewController has a [navigationController property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621860-navigationcontroller?language=objc).  This property is nil if the ViewController is not part of a navigation stack.