# UINavigationBar won't show again after hiding on scroll/swipe

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, statusbar

As the title says, the navigationBar doesn't show up after hiding it on scroll. I tried setting it in xCode as well as programmatically. Either way, the problem is still there. 
[image]

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }
```

Here is what it looks like after hiding the navBar. Note that the status bar color also changed color from white to black.

[image]

In viewDidLoad I have :

```
 //MARK: navigation bar styles
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 26/255, green: 24/255, blue: 24/255, alpha: 1)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =  [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"GillSans", size: 20)!]
```

Does anyone have a good solution for this? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: did you use another navigationController in code ?

Comment: can you post your viewDidLoad?

Comment: @KKRocks I don't think so. I tried to use self.navigationController and it is still the same

Comment: @Joe I just updated the question, you can find the code in viewDidLoad in the question. Thanks

Comment: Code uploaded....Worth to mention there is more ways to achieve this. Let me know. Is that what you want....

Comment: If you don't wanna change plist. That's ok..code still work.your background looks white when you hide navBar.so you  have to update your statusBar content again to default.. its  a tricky business... let me know

Comment: If you not sure what I am talking about.check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059328/change-status-bar-color-in-real-time/40061614#40061614

Comment: If you still having issue. Let me know.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

**Note :** As you setting your navbar background close to black. You have to change your status bar content to light.

//Update your plist with below code

```
 View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

In your ViewController:

```
    title = "Some Title"

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 26/255, green: 24/255, blue: 24/255, alpha: 1)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    //Title Colour and Font
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"Arial", size: 20)!]

    navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = false
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
   }


   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

    }
```

output:

[image]

Comment: What's the reason for updating the plist file? I have made the status bar become white by using this code:   //Change Status bar style
    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }   The navigationBar still won't appear after scrolling.