# Changing status bar style mid-scroll

Tags: ios, swift

Since `setStatusBarStyle` was deprecated in iOS 10, is there a way to change my status bar from white to black or vice versa while doing something like scrolling through a scroll view?

I see the `preferredStatusBarStyle` property on `UIViewController` but I'd like something more granular that I can control while a user uses the view controller itself.

Comment: Have you tried calling this `set​Needs​Status​Bar​Appearance​Update()`? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621354-setneedsstatusbarappearanceupdat

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059328/change-status-bar-color-in-real-time/40061614#40061614

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you override preferredStatusBarStyle and then call setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() when you need, that should work the same way.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return currentStyle
    }
    // ...

    // here are the actions that change the status bar
    func myFunction(){
        // ...
        // condition that would determine the preferred style
        currentStyle = .lightContent
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgio. Appreciate it